# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Oracle SQL Dev

Tags: sql, oracle, connection

When i'm trying to connect to the database, which is located at my university I get the following error "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection". All of my friends had no problems connecting. I've tried googling it, but none of the solutions worked, or i could not figure out how to do it. For example I couldn't find any Oracle services i was supposed to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

To access a database you need three things:

- the host name where the database is running  (night club address)
- the database service (ie, what that host is "offering" to the outside world)
- the port number (what port the host will allow access on).

Even if you know these things, there are certain things that must be running on the database host.  Think of it like a nightclub - even if you know the address, the only way you get in if the door is being manned by the door man so he can let you in.  So the database "listener" must be running on the database host.  If others can get in, then thats a good sign it is running.

So you need those three things:

- host name
- service name
- port number

Get any of those wrong and you'll likely see errors like the one you're seeing

Comment: That was my first thought too, but i checked it multiple times. I spoke to my professor today and he said it could be that my ISP provider is blocking my connection, is that possible?

Comment: more likely the other way around, the university is blocking your traffic. are your friends on the university network via dorm or library? take your laptop where they are and give it a whirl